# Несколько smtp на одном сервере

Tags: postfix

Доброго дня!Имеется установленный почтовый сервер на Debian 7 - Postfix + Dovecot + Amavisd + Roundcube, то есть стандартная сборка iRedMail.Имеется программа для e-mail рассылки, в настройках которой можно указывать неограниченное количество smtp серверов для отправки писем.Причем, при подключении каждого нового smtp сервера в настройках этой программы надо указать такие параметры:

1. SMTP Hostname: (укажите 56.78.78.89 или mail.my-site.ru), обязательное поле
2. SMTP Имя пользователя: не обязательное поле
3. SMTP пароль: не обязательное поле
4. SMTP Port: не обязательное поле

Эта программа установлена на этом же выделенном виртуальном сервере в /var/www/ и использует для отправки по умолчанию /usr/sbin/sendmailВопрос заключается в следующем:Как настроить эти самые smtp сервера, с разными IP на базе одного Postfix

Answer (score 1):

Что подразумевается под «разными SMTP серверам»? Один Postfix может обслуживать несколько доменов и слушать несколько IP адресов (и эти два факта никак между собой не связаны).

Если вы хотите что-бы Postfix был доступен из интернета по нескольким IP адресам (слабо представляю зачем вам это) то добавьте на виртуалку дополнительные IP (обратитесь к своему хостеру), скорее всего Postfix либо сам начнёт их использовать после перезапуска, но возможно потребуется небольшая его переконфигурация.

Если вы хотите что-бы Postfix работал SMTP сервером для нескольких доменов то придётся покопаться в его настройках (исчерпывающая информация о настройке постфикса содержится в The Book of Postfix (в русском издании «Postfix. Подробное руководство»)). Все виденные мною HOWTO по Postfix (и вообще по email) показались мне весьма сомнительными (в основном это пошаговые инструкции для получения почтовой системы идентичной используемой автором HOWTO) и не предполагающими понимания своих действий. Так-что отсылаю сразу к книге.

Если вы хотите что-бы упомянутая вами программа для рассылки спама использовала ваш постфикс как несколько серверов (опять-таки не понимаю зачем) то можете просто использовать IP-адреса из подсети 127.0.0.0/8. Назначьте их loopback интерфейсу, научите постфикс их использовать (см. выше) и забейте в свою программу хоть все 16777214 адресов этой подсети (: